# Multiple new columns dependent on other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

`Node Node1 Length Spaces Dist T
1   2   600 30  300 100
1   3   400 20  200 100
2   1   600 30  300 100
2   6   500 25  250 400
3   1   400 20  200 100
3   4   400 20  200 200
3   12  400 20  200 200
4   3   400 20  200 200
4   5   200 10  100 500
4   11  600 30  300 1400
5   4   200 10  100 500
5   6   400 20  200 200
5   9   500 25  250 800
6   2   500 25  250 400
6   5   400 20  200 200
6   8   200 10  100 800`

This tells us that, for example in the first row, there are 30 spaces between nodes 1 and 2. How could I create, say, 30 new columns with a value of 1 to represent each space seperately. Then do the same for each row.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work (col 'A' is your 'NoSpaces'):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
max_val = df['A'].max()
for itr in range(max_val):
    colname = 'A%d' % itr
    df[colname] = (df['A'] >=itr).astype('int')
```

Comment: Would there be a way such that rather than each value being 1, it can increase by 20 each time? i.e in the first row space 1 would have value 1 and space 2 would have value 20..

Comment: add to the last row *20*itr so it will be: df[colname] = (df['A'] >=itr).astype('int')*20*itr. but pay attention that the first column is 0